# News feed customization

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, newsfeed

Is there possible to modify news feed webpart to display less information (to make it shorter)?

And one more question - can I set alert to any new post or new topic on news feed? Not only my posts and answers for them - for all news feeds.